# Topological Surfaces Transformation

Tags: general-topology

Is there any topological theory that states that any topological shapes can be transformed to each other as long as they have the same amount of holes?

Comment: Hello Omar. I believe this question might get a better answer in Math SE.

Comment: Also, when you ask there, you may want to be more specific as to what kind of shapes and transformations you want to consider. For three dimensions, this is obviously wrong as two intertwined rings cannot be transformed into two separate rings (at least for all common definitions of *transform* I am aware of).